# How to give control back to the main function - jQuery, JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing code for an API call website as an exercise. I've wrote a function to get the data and another one to render article snippets to the page. My intention is to be able to clear the page in order to display full article content.

I'm using jQuery functions to achieve that. My problem is that after invoking a function for rendering article snippets I'm not able to invoke any other function in the `$(document).ready()` part (as the control seems to be still sitting inside `renderSnippet` function).

I want to be able to invoke `News.clearView` from `$(document).ready()` but it doesn't happen. However, if I invoke it from inside of `renderSnippet` function, it works.

So my question is: how do I get back to `$(document).ready()` part after calling `renderSnippet`? I tried experimenting with `return` statements but that didn't help.

*apiquery.js*

```
var News = {
    get: function(query, callback) {          
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://content.guardianapis.com/search",
            type: "GET",
            data: query,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(json) {
                callback(json.response.results);     
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
                console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                console.log("Status: " + status);
                console.dir(xhr);
            },

        });  
    },
    renderSnippet: function(quantity, query) {
        News.get(query, function(data) {
        $.get("views/home.html", function(contents) {
            // renders snippets to home page
            for(var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
                var helper = contents;
                helper = helper.replace("${Title}", data[i].webTitle);
                helper = helper.replace("${Snippet}", data[i].fields.standfirst);
                $('div.news').append(helper);
            }
            //News.clearView(); // This one works
        }, 'html');

        });
    },
    clearView: function() {
        $('div.news').empty();
    }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    News.renderSnippet(10, "q=technology&show-fields=all&api-key=test");
    News.clearView(); // This is not working
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. `clearview()` will complete before `renderSnippet`. Why are you trying to empty the element you are trying to populate anyway? Objective is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback method there as well like you have used in the get function.

```
 renderSnippet: function(quantity, query,callback) {
    News.get(query, function(data) {
    $.get("views/home.html", function(contents) {
        // renders snippets to home page
        for(var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            var helper = contents;
            helper = helper.replace("${Title}", data[i].webTitle);
            helper = helper.replace("${Snippet}", data[i].fields.standfirst);
            $('div.news').append(helper);
        }
        //News.clearView(); // This one works
         calllback();
    }, 'html');

    });
},
```

And in the document ready you can make a call like this

```
News.renderSnippet(10, "q=technology&show-fields=all&api-key=test",function(){
    News.clearView();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because `$.get` is an **asynchronous function**. So, when you call the `News.renderSnippet`, it will immediately execute the `$.get`, and before the callback you pass to `$.get` is executed, your `News.clearView` method will have already been executed.

You must change your `News.renderSnippet` to receive a callback function and then, call it like this:

```
renderSnippet: function(quantity, query, cb) {
    News.get(query, function(data) {
      $.get("views/home.html", function(contents) {
        // renders snippets to home page
        for(var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            var helper = contents;
            helper = helper.replace("${Title}", data[i].webTitle);
            helper = helper.replace("${Snippet}", data[i].fields.standfirst);
            $('div.news').append(helper);
        }
        cb();
      }, 'html');
    });
}
```

So, in your `$(document).ready` event, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    News.renderSnippet(10, "q=technology&show-fields=all&api-key=test", function() {
        News.clearView(); // This will work
    });
});
```